# Two models to store in database as one transaction

Tags: laravel, transactions, laravel-5.1

I have two models **Item** and **ItemDetail** and they have a **one-to-many** relationship

One-to-many because I store the item details as Entity–attribute–value Table, it is nothing but a table the columns and label and value that stores ItemDetails as following

```
id|item_id_fkey|Label         |Value
1 |1           |Color         |Black
2 |1           |Description   |Item 1 Details
3 |1           |Size          |2x4x6
4 |2           |Description   |Item 2 Details
5 |2           |Weight        |1000
```

When I create an *Item* it ask me *Item->name* and *Item->Price*, on Submit it calls the **ItemsController@store** and redirect to **ItemDetailController@create** with newly created item id.

**ItemDetailsController@create** redirects to a Form with lot more fields to for gathering item details (e.g. ItemDetail->Description, ItemDetail->Dimensions etc), and on submit it stores the ItemDetails model.

**Problem**:(*Not as complex as the situation*), The issue is I want it to be such that if user creates item in first form and does not update the item details in second form, item shouldn't present in Item table as well.
In another words two store methods should be one single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You can put everything in one form (may require creating dynamic HTML elements) and make your controller's `store()` method check if there's a non-empty array of values for the `ItemDetail` model. If there are values, create the `Item` model and the `ItemDetail` model(s), abort otherwise.

**Solution 2:**

You can have your `ItemDetailsController@store` method accept an `$itemId` which represents the newly created `Item` model and, as above, check if there's a non-empty array of values for the `ItemDetail` model(s) then create or abort.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand Solution 1. But as per your solution 2 I have `ItemDetailsController@store` method accept an `$itemId` but by this time itemId is already stored in item table and if user aborts before submitting the item details, I have item but no item details. I want to avoid that.

Comment: For __Solution 1__ you can put a button on your form that when clicked will add an input element for the `ItemDetail`. That way you can add as many `ItemDetail` as you want. For  __Solution 2__ you can delete the stored `Item` if there are no `ItemDetail`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the two forms you are referring to are on separate pages and therefore are two separate requests to the server.

You could save the information in the first form in an object and pass it to the session.

Controller for First Form:

```
public function handleFirstForm() {

    //perform validation and any other logic

    $input = Input::get('contentsOfFirstForm');

    Session::put('contentsOfFirstForm', $input);
}
```

The array you put into the session will only be used if the customer proceeds to fill out the item details.

Controller for Second Form:

```
public function handleSecondForm() {

    $input = Input::get('contentsOfSecondForm');       

    //only save if the second form is not blank
    if($input!==null) {

        //run any other logic

        //Save First Form
        $item = Session::get('contentsOfFirstForm');
        Item::create([$item]);

        //Save Second Form
        $itemDetails = $input;
        ItemDetail::create([$item]);

    }
}
```

You may also want to do a check using model events to see if the first form successfully saved, and ONLY then, save the second form, to prevent cases where your second model successfully saved, but the first model for whatever reason could not be saved.